# Asp.net - Update Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a comment windows right under the photos.

```
<div class="post commentPanel" id="pnlComment">
                    <div class="post-footer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" imgId='<%# Eval("PID") %>' ID="btnSendComment" OnClick="btnSendComment_Click" Text="Send"></asp:Button>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="comments-list">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="uptComment" UpdateMode="Always">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listComment" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder" DataSource='<%# Eval("CommentList")%>'>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <li class="comment">
                                                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                                    <img class="avatar" src='<%# Eval("UserImg") %>' alt="avatar">
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="comment-body">
                                                    <div class="comment-heading">
                                                        <h4 class="user"><%# Eval("UserFName") %> <%# Eval("UserSName")%></h4>
                                                        <h5 class="time">(<%# Eval("CDate") %>)</h5>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p><%# Eval("CText") %></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:ListView>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>



protected void btnSendComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var x = sender as Button;
                ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)(sender as Control).NamingContainer;
                TextBox txtComment = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtComment");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtComment.Text) == false)
                {
                    Comment comm = new Comment()
                    {
                        CText = txtComment.Text,
                        PID = x.Attributes["imgId"],
                        UID = Session["loginuser"].ToString(),
                        CDate = DateTime.Now,
                    };
                    if (Comment.sendComment(comm) == true)
                    {
                        txtComment.Text = string.Empty;
                        ListView listComment = (ListView)item.FindControl("listComment");
                        List<Comment> commlist = SqlTask.GetCommentsByPhotoId(comm.PID);
                        listComment.DataSource = commlist;
                        uptMain.Update();
                    }

            }
        }
```

I have a listview like above. When a user post a comment for photo, I can see it after refresh the page but it is so unhandy as you guess.
I also cover my listview with a updatepanel, to be honest Im not sure how the updatepanel works.

So Im just trying to refresh comment panel after a comment sending. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The `UpdatePanel` will turn into Ajax calls all the postbacks being performed **inside** the panel, so you should move the button inside the UpdatePanel.

Check this example based on your code:

Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdatePanel.aspx.cs" Inherits="AspNetDemoProject.Demos.UpdatePanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="post commentPanel" id="pnlComment">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="uptComment" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="post-footer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtComment" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" imgId='<%# Eval("PID") %>' ID="btnSendComment" OnClick="btnSendComment_Click" Text="Send"></asp:Button>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="comments-list">
                            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listComment" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li class="comment">
                                        <p><%# Eval("Text") %></p>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Beside:

```
public partial class UpdatePanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();


        protected void btnSendComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list.Add(new { Text = txtComment.Text });
        }

        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listComment.DataSource = list;
            listComment.DataBind();
        }
    }
```